# Blazor rendering content twice

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5

I've tried different ways to prevent this from happening.

After changing to `render-mode="Server"` I was able to prevent rendering twice on the first load.

But now when I refresh the page it still doubles the amount of elements.

Here is what I've got

```
<div id="component-wrapper" class="row">
    @if (Items != null)
    {
        @foreach (var item in Items )
        {
            <ItemComponent Item="@item" />
        }
    }
</div>

@code {

    [Inject]
    private IItemService ItemService { get; set; }
    List<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Items = await ItemService.GetItemsAsync();
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

I've read over the [Stateful reconnection after prerendering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0#stateful-reconnection-after-prerendering) section and it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: "when I refresh the page it still doubles the amount of elements"?? Are you saying that `Items` contains everything twice and thus `foreach` doubles up on `ItemComponent`?  Is so check 'GetItemsAsync. ' Also note that when the Blazor Server SPA first loads it calls the page twice - the first time to statically render the page on the server, then a second time when the client side Blazor code calls back to the Blazor Hub to get a fully wired up page.

Answer (score 6):

For me it was that this script was duplicated on _Hosts.cshtml

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

After deleting one of them problem was solved.

Answer (score 6):

In case of Blazor Server, modifying `_Host.cshtml` solved this for me:

before

```
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

after

```
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
```

Comment: in this mode, you lost the content for SEO.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who is hitting this "loading twice" with .Net 8 and "AutoRender" mode.  I found this post to be valuable:

[https://jonhilton.net/persist-state-between-renders-net8/#:~:text=Chances%20are%20it's%20down%20to,show%20something%20nice%20and%20quickly](https://jonhilton.net/persist-state-between-renders-net8/#:%7E:text=Chances%20are%20it%27s%20down%20to,show%20something%20nice%20and%20quickly).

> By default in .NET 8 your interactive components are rendered twice:
>
> Once on the server (prerendering), where HTML is returned so the
> browser can show something nice and quickly.
>
> Then your component will be rendered again using your preferred
> interactive render mode (server or WASM).
>
> The problem is, if you’re fetching data in your component, it’s going
> to be fetched for both renders.
>
> You can often see this in the UI, with a visible flash as the
> prerendered content is replaced with the “new data” when your
> component is rendered for a second time.
>
> So what to do about it? Turns out there are two main options at your
> disposal:
>
> Disable prerendering Persist state between the first and second
> renders

Answer (score 0):

Turns out in a further down stream service where I've added to the list, I wasn't creating an empty list to begin with.

Thanks for assisting.

Comment: NP. `OnInitializedAsync` is the correct place for your code. Could you please tick off the question as answered?

Answer (score -2):

Don't override OnInitialized
Use OnAfterRender or OnAfterRenderAsync

> protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)

With firstRender you get the info.
You can also use our own mecanism to avoid loading your context more than one time.

If needed call StateHasChanged to update the DOM.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0

EDIT

The easiest way to solve this problem is to use browser localstorage. You can save user id and then get it back in case of a refresh.
If a user press F5 to refresh the page, blazor will create a new circuit and there is no easy solution on the server side.

Comment: That still doesn't work, perhaps you can write the code from what I've shown you and I will test it.

Comment: Look at localstorage and see my answer edit.