# Blazor Web App component content renders twice - how to change render mode (.NET 8)?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, server-side-rendering, prerender, .net-8.0

I have used Blazor Server previously (.NET 6) but am new to .NET 8. I created a new Blazor Web project (interactive render mode: auto, interactivity mode: per page/component). My server component content is rendering twice. In earlier versions of Blazor I could prevent this by changing the render mode in the *_Host.cshtml* file (see [Blazor rendering content twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66503874/blazor-rendering-content-twice)) but this file is not present in the new Blazor Web App.

How do I change the render mode in .NET 8 in order to render content once?

I have already tried adding `@rendermode InteractiveServer` to the top of my Home page as well as adding `<Routes @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveServer" />` to my App.razor file but the page continues to render twice.

Comment: This my be what you're looking for - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#prerendering

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the issue. Dumb error but I will go ahead and post the solution just in case someone runs into the same problem. I had transferred some previously-written code into MainLayout.razor and didn't notice that the @Body statement was listed twice  (in two places within the document).